# visual studio 2022 installs monoframework 6.12.0.174 on mac, then iOS Simulator fails

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I use Visual Studio 2022 on Windows for Xamarin development for Android & iOS. I use a Mac Mini with M1 for the iOS builds. All has been working fine for over a month. A few days ago I allowed the MAC to perform an update. Today when I tried to build for iOS, the Pair To Mac dialog said there was a monoframework mismatch and offered to install monoframework 6.12.0.174 on the MAC. Initially I chose Cancel,and then rebooted both machines. The same error occurred when I tried again. This time I allowed the install. After the install completed, every time I try to use the iOS Simulator it hangs as soon as it appears. I would appreciate some direction. I do not know how to fix it and I do not know how to back-out the mono install on the MAC. Please help.

Comment: I updated Visual Studio 2022 for Windows to the current version (17.1.4). I updated Visual Studio 2019 for Mac to the current version (8.10.22 build 11), the monoframework mdk on the Mac still shows 6.12.0.174) Pair to Mac now completes but when the iOS simulator launches, it fails with Error Connecting to the Broker.

Comment: There might really be a version mismatch. If so, Microsoft usually corrects the problem in a day or two. In the meantime: 1) Are you able to build on the Mac directly (rather than from pc)? 2) Try pairing from VS 2019 on PC - does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I updated Visual Studio & Visual Studio for Mac to the current versions. Then found in the following in the Visual Studio ReleaseNotes:
Known Issues
Deploying an iOS app with Visual Studio 2022 and Apple Xcode 13.3 results in a Remote iOS simulator window with a blank/black screen. Workaround: Disable the “Remote Simulator to Windows” check box in the iOS Settings under the Tools - Options menu. The iOS app should deploy correctly on the macOS host.
Following those instructions I disabled the “Remote Simulator to Windows” check box in the iOS Settings under the Tools - Options menu. The iOS app then deployed correctly, but on the macOS host, no longer can it deploy on the Windows machine from the Mac build host as in prior versions.